# How do I physically print both the code and the console in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to Eclipse and I want to know how I can print my output because CTRL+P only prints the code I wrote. I usually take a screenshot, but there has to be an easy way to like change the settings to print them that I haven't found yet.

Comment: You could write the output directly to a file.

Comment: try to search file i/o in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, write the output to a text file in your directory.